# Give fields_for have access to additional model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, formbuilder

I'm trying to render a page where a user can answer a `Survey` (thus creating an `Application`). I can return the questions easily (`@survey.questions`) and I can render forms for answering questions too using the builder helper.

Controller:

```
@survey.questions.each do |question|
  @application.answers.build
end
```

View:

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.text_area :answer %>
<% end %>
```

But the problem is that this only renders the text areas to answer the questions, without the actual question text.

What's the correct way of combining the two so I can display both the question and allow the user to answer it?

Being able to do something like this would be great:

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
  Q: <%= question.question %>
  A: <%= builder.text_area :answer %>
<% end %>
```

PS If someone can suggest a better title please do.

Comment: You are not using the variable `question` in that `do` block.

Comment: I know, that's my question: how should I pass through the questions from the controller along with the form builders for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
  Q: <%= builder.label builder.object.question %>
  A: <%= builder.text_area :answer %>
<% end %>
```

If it reports an error for the `question` call on `builder.object`, do a `builder.object.inspect` to see what kind of object is that.

Comment: Accepting this because it gets the object directly without array indexes but had to modify the controller to get it working because the object will always have nil values in the template if you're using builder.

Answer (score 1):

As of Rails 4.0.2, you have access to index on the builder object.

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
  Q: <%= @suvery.questions[builder.index].question %>
  A: <%= builder.text_area :answer %>
<% end %>
```